# Can JavaScript embedded in a web page access the URL parameters of the page request?

Tags: html, javascript, url

Can JavaScript embedded in a served HTML page access the page-request URL, including its parameters?

Comment: Of course, see `href` (or `search` and `hash`) [in Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location). That said, this question is off-topic on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location.search will return a string. If you need to parse that string to pick out the param(s) you find useful then may I suggest the following:

```
    var obj = {}; 
            str.replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function(m, key, value) {
            obj[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    });
```

If in your URL querystring param list you had a param such as 'userId=591' then to retrieve this from the object you would just use `obj.userId`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object (lwburk's answer). Using a custom function to `replace()` this way is tried and tested for this. My first encounter with this technique was in 2011 but predates the code given above so its cross-browser compatibility is v.good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's available through `window.location.search`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Comment: As an aside, please see [Discouraging w3schools as a resource](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource).